# Obtain permalink for post via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm currently working on a Wordpress website for the first time, in one of my views I load content dynamically via AJAX, but this information doesn't include the permalink for the posts I load. I wanted to know how I can get the permalink for a post via AJAX by providing the post ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This WordPress function returns the permalink for a given ID.

[get_permalink()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink)

Back-end:

```
<?php

    add_action('wp_ajax_get_permalink', 'ajax_get_permalink');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_permalink', 'ajax_get_permalink');

    function ajax_get_permalink(){
        echo get_permalink(intval($_REQUEST['id']));
        die();
    }

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax_get_permalink', 'ajax_get_permalink', array(
        ajax_url =>  admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )  
    ));

?>
```

Front-end:

```
var data = {
    action: 'get_permalink',
    id: the_post_id
};

jQuery.post(ajax_get_permalink.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
    permalink = response;
});
```

Comment: Where would I place what goes in the backend? just a stand alone PHP file?

Comment: If in a theme, place it in functions.php in the theme folder.

Comment: Getting this Uncaught ReferenceError: ajax_get_permalink is not defined

Comment: Just worked it out, needed a little tuning but this was the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

use `get_permalink($your_post_id)`

in your php code on the server and pass it back.

you can read more about the function [HERE](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink)